# Detecting Language and converting the same to english

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nltk, language-detection

I have a list of strings which are in japanese language, I would want my code to detect the language on its own and convert the same to english.

I have deployed the below code

```
from google_trans_new import google_translator  

detector = google_translator()  
detect_result = detector.detect('小')
# Detect text  
print(detect_result)
```

Error for detection
Exception:

```
from google_trans_new import google_translator

translator = google_translator()

sentence = "アフィリエイト代理店 打合せ 商談"
translate_text = translator.translate(sentence,lang_tgt='en') 

print(translate_text)
```

Error for translation

JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 466 (char 465)*

But I'm getting error as shown above, request for help.

Comment: What's the Exception message for detection error ?   Also, not recommended to detect using the word 小 as it can also be a Chinese.

Comment: Open ATM: [json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 300 (char 299)](https://github.com/lushan88a/google_trans_new/issues/36)

Comment: No I googled 小,  it is japanese. One of the reason why I'm trying to code to detect the language itself.

Comment: This was fixed here. https://github.com/lushan88a/google_trans_new/commit/e543e86465b43cd54669e4adb48ffa7adddba0f8#diff-809a64e7c1fb9dd90fc1411f7e22e575247e64ea52afb4797a9360f6065a5258

Comment: Changing `response = (decoded_line + ']')` on line 151 and 233 to `response = decoded_line` should fix the issue. It looks like it hasn't made it to pip yet.

Comment: The word 小 can both be a Japanese and Chinese, so if you rely on detection to set the language, my point is don't choose one that can have multiple possible results.  Ask your Japanese working partner to choose a better word for you.

Comment: @Axe319 I think the response has been rectified in the parent file, not sure how to go about, can you please guide.

Comment: @SeaBean I will consider the input, however I would like to emphasis on accuracy for translation. When I individually check the japanese sentence on google translate it seems to be translating good enough, trying to achieve that through an API.

Comment: @Sid in your Python installation directory in the `Lib\site-packages\google_trans_new\google_trans_new.py` file. Either change the lines I mentioned above or pull the latest version of the file from github here. https://github.com/lushan88a/google_trans_new/blob/main/google_trans_new.py

Comment: @Axe319 I updated the line, however I'm getting the following error now JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 502 (char 501)

Comment: @Axe319 Seems to be working post restating the system, thank you.